# Keep scripts injected on individual posts from showing on index.php

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using a wordpress plugin, HIFI (head injection, foot injection) that injects jQuery scripts into individual posts from the WP dashboard.

The trouble is, all of the scripts that I've ever used on individual posts are being injected into the head on the index (home) page too. Makes for a pretty messy user experience with all these animations happening at once.

Any thoughts on how to keep that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin uses wp_enqueue_scripts(), this might work?

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_de_script', 100 );

if ( is_home() ) {
    function my_de_script() {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'foo' );
        }
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't use it, unfortunately. Just inserts a script in the head.

Comment: Ok then!  I looked at the plugin.  It is hooking into the wp_head and creating an action that inserts the scripts.  It looks like calling remove_action() right after that might do the trick.  How about if you put this in your header.php file right after the call to wp_head()?

`<?php if( is_home() ) { remove_action( 'wp_head', 'hifi_head_inject' ); } ?>`